# Listando dados duplicados ao realizar SQL e realizar .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax, delete, load

procurei em diversos lugares, inclusive na documentação do jQuery e não achei uma solução. Preciso de uma luz do que fazer nessa ocasião. Peço desculpas se não ficar muito claro, nunca fui muito de participar de fórum e de pedir ajuda nessa parte de programação.

O sistema é MVC. Eu realizo a listagem fazendo o `load()` de uma página html na minha `<div class="conteudo">`, e dentro desse html externo, possui um `<table>` e um `<script>` da listagem desses dados.

Isso funciona normalmente, listando os dados em seus devidos lugares na tabela, porém, quando eu faço um **DELETE** na tabela, ele retorna no `.done()`, um `load()`  novamente nessa minha `div` com a página de listagem (html externo), e o pulo do gato está ai, ele lista os dados após o **DELETE**, duplicados.

[image: Quando eu aperto o botão "Alunos cdastrados" ele listará os dados com o html importado]
Quando eu aperto o botão "Alunos cadastrados" ele listará os dados com o html importado

[image: Ao clicar na lixeira (Deletado o id=4), ele deleta o registra e faz a importação do html novamente, porém com dados repetidos]
Ao clicar na lixeira (Deletado o `id`=4), ele deleta o registro e faz a importação do html novamente para listar a nova tabela, porém com dados repetidos

Se precisar, aqui está o código `html` externo que estou importando para dentro da minha página:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive-sm display compact cell-border" id="alunos" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nome</th>
            <th scope="col">RM</th>
            <th scope="col">Celular</th>
            <th scope="col">OP</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script src="src/alunos/controller/list-alunos.js"></script>
<script src="src/alunos/controller/delete-aluno.js"></script>
```

O `delete-aluno.js` que realiza o **DELETE**:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.conteudo').on('click', '.btn-delete-aluno', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'src/alunos/model/delete-aluno.php',
            data: `id_aluno=${$(this).attr('id')}`,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST'
        }).done((retorno) => {
            $(".conteudo").load('src/alunos/view/list-alunos.html')
        })
    })
})
```

E o `list-aluno.js` que faz a listagem, não sei se será necessário consultar esse script:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(document).empty()
    $.ajax({
        url: 'src/alunos/model/list-alunos',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done((retorno) => {
        for (const dado of retorno) {
            $("#alunos").append(
                `
                 <tr role="row">
                    <td>${dado.id_aluno}</td>
                    <td>${dado.nome}</td>
                    <td>${dado.rm}</td>
                    <td>${dado.celular}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn-delete-aluno" id="${dado.id_aluno}">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                `
            )
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, parece que você não está limpando a tabela antes de recarregar os dados.

Tente criar um **TBODY** após o **THEAD** e dar o **.append()** nele (após limpá-lo):

```html
 <!-- tabela -->
 ...
 </thead>
 <tbody id="lista-alunos"></tbody>
```

E para limpar, use o **empty()**

```js
   ...
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done((retorno) => {
        $("#lista-alunos").empty() //limpar todas as linhas que estavam na tabela
        for (const dado of retorno) {
            $("#lista-alunos").append( //acrescentar novas que vieram do servidor
   ...
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou, e além do mais, melhorou o front-end, deixou mais bonito a tabela esse <tbody>, bom dia.

Comment: Que bom que funcionou, queira marcar a resposta como aceita. Precisando, estamos aí.